# CMake: satisfying dependencies when building shared object file (.so) from object file (.o)

Tags: cmake

I am able to do this without CMake using a handwritten Makefile, like so:

```
g++  $(CXSCINC) -c -fPIC cellComplex_extern.cpp -o cellComplex_extern.o  
g++  $(CXSCINC) -shared -Wl -o cellComplex_lib.so cellComplex_extern.o $(CXSCLIB) -lcxsc
```

This gets me shared library `cellComplex_lib.so`, which then gets picked up by `ctypes` as a dynamically linked library (`lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./cellComplex_lib.so'`) for later use.

My project has moved to CMake as a build system and I am looking to emulate the functionality of my Makefile above.

So far I have discovered the `add_library()` command for CMakeLists.txt, but the link to the CXSC library is never made (as evidenced by horrible complaining when I run `make` after `cmake`.

**How can I tell CMake to build `cellComplex_lib` with the third-party library CXSC?**

-- non-working `CMakeLists.txt` --

```
add_library(include/python/cellComplex_extern OBJECT
            include/python/cellComplex_extern.cpp ${all_headers})

add_library(include/python/cellComplex_lib SHARED
            include/python/cellComplex_extern)
target_link_libraries(include/python/cellComplex_lib ${CXSC_LIB_DIR}/libcxsc.a)
```

Result of running cmake followed by make:

```
.
.
.
[ 75%] Built target include/python/cellComplex_extern
Linking CXX shared library libinclude/python/cellComplex_lib.dylib
ld: can't open output file for writing: libinclude/python/cellComplex_lib.dylib, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libinclude/python/cellComplex_lib.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/include/python/cellComplex_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Seems like you have a path problem now. Or is the lib in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `target_link_libraries`

```
target_link_libraries(include/python/cellComplex_lib ${CXSLIB})
```

This is what I use during Win32 development:

```
link_directories(${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/lib ${LIB_ROOT_DIR2}/lib/morelibs)
add_library(MyDll1 SHARED File1.cpp File2.cpp)
add_library(MyDll2 SHARED File3.cpp File4.cpp)
add_dependencies(MyDll2 Dll1)
target_link_libraries(MyDll2 Dll1 some.lib another.lib)
```

Here you specify that Dll2 requires Dll1 and two other external lib's.

Comment: I seem to be unable to use `target_link_libraries()` when the target is the library I just added with `add_library`.  The error is `ld: can't open output file for writing: <target_lib>`.  I tried a few more things and edited my question.  Thanks though, I think this is awfully close to what I am looking for.

Comment: In that case you need to add add_dependency, I will add it to the answer